# Group By ranges in Linq

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

Thanks all, I am sorry but I am very beginner. Let me explain it in details: I have a table "theTable" and has two columns "Date" in DateTime and "Value" in double.
What I want as a result: 1.check which date is the minimum 2. Take this as firstdat

I have tried but seems not working

```
from cf in theTable.
group t by  t.Month.Month / 8 + t.Month.Year into g 

select new { sum = g.Sum(x=>x.Amount) ,year = g.Key}
```

Comment: `.GroupBy` with some key like `arg => arg.MyDateTime.Year`?? what have you tried so far? what is your class-layout?

Comment: Can you show some code? Are your values in your 'Date' column strings or DateTime?

Comment: If you take the integer division of the month by 8 and add it to the year it will give each group a unique key.

Comment: I use Date as DateTime. I have tried : 
            var ranges = new List<int> { 0, 12 };

            var defaultGroups =
                  (from h in Table
                   let daysFromToday = (today)
                   group h by ranges.FirstOrDefault(range => daysFromToday.Month < range) into g

                   select g);

Comment: Here it is, hope that helps

Comment: Can you edit your question if that comment is relevant?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do something like that:

```
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var columns = new List<Column>();

        var dateRanges = new List<DateRange>()
        {
            new DateRange(new DateTime(2013, 09, 03), new DateTime(2014, 09, 03))
        };

        var result = columns.GroupBy(
            column => dateRanges.FirstOrDefault(dr => dr.IsInRange(column.Date)),
            (dr, drc) => new KeyValuePair<DateRange, int>(dr, drc.Sum(v => v.Value)));
    }

    public struct DateRange
    {
        public DateRange(DateTime from, DateTime to)
            : this()
        {
            From = from;
            To = to;
        }

        public bool IsInRange(DateTime date)
        {
            return date >= From && date <= To;
        }

        public DateTime From { get; private set; }
        public DateTime To { get; private set; }
    }

    public class Column
    {
        public int Value { get; set; }
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
theTable.GroupBy(t => t.Date.Month / 8 + t.Date.Year)
.Select(g => g.Sum(x = > x.Value));
```

If you take the range 8/1991-7/1992 for instance they will both end up in the same group:

8 / 8 + 1991 = 7 / 8 + 1992 = 1992

Comment: `.GroupBy` expects a `Func<TSource, TKey` for the key selector

Answer (score -1):

```
myList.Where(x=> x.Date < lastDate && x.Date > firstDate).Sum(x=>x.Value)
```

Not sure of the answer because the question is not really clear but this is the sum of all the  property "Value" of your list which property "Date" is between a date firstDate and a date LastDate.

Comment: Could you please add some description to your answer?

Comment: here you go ! (i expected more details of the owner of the post to put more details but whatever...)